# Sine series using exponential based FFT

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have such a problem - I would need to expand a discrete function in a sine fourier series but I would like to use exponential based library for FFT (I will use CUDA to compute it).
What have I to do with the signal I'm sending to the procedure so this is treated as sine fourier? I think I should add zeros but I am not sure where they have to be.
Many thanks

Comment: The library you want to use can't directly do a DST?

Comment: I would like to write the code both for MKL and CUDA. In CUDA, I don't know about Sine Library. And in MKL, the exponential based FFT is available in native MPI parallelization form as well but the sine version not.

Comment: There are at least [four DSTs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_sine_transform#Definition); I presume you want DST-I?

Comment: yes, DST-I is that

Comment: Then, have you seen [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=ozcvQUqr-GIC&pg=PA232)?